# Classifying fuction $x + \frac{x^2}{\sqrt{x-1}}$

Tags: calculus

$x + \frac{x^2}{\sqrt{x-1}}$

"Classify each function as a power function, root function, polynomial (State degree), rational function, algebraic function, exponential function"

This function is confusing because it has attributes of several different types. It can't be a rational function because there is the $x$ to the side. That $x$ is also the reason it can't be a power function either, unless maybe if you consider the $x$ to have degree 1

Comment: say that is a composition of polynomial, root functions and power function ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$x + \frac{x^2}{\sqrt{x-1}} = \dfrac{x\sqrt{x-1} + x^2}{\sqrt{x - 1}}$$

But note that this does not make the function a *rational* function, because a rational function requires that the numerator and denominator are polynomials, which is not the case here.

Comment: Exactly what I just wrote on a piece of paper. Heh. ;-)